# UIScrollView - is it possible to know whether scrolled by hand or programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

Is it possible to know whether the UIScrollVIew is scrolled manually or programmatically ? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `tracking` and/or `dragging` properties of the `UIScrollView`.